# Python - compare ranges between two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

For df1:

```
    Country fruit   low high
0   Spain   orange  100 20000
1   Italy   apple   500 50000
2   Aus     grape   300 10000
```

and df2:

```
    City    fruit   low high
0   sample1 orange  50  200
1   sample1 apple   10  400
2   sample2 orange  25000   50000
3   sample3 orange  50  300
4   sample3 grape   350 1000
5   sample3 grape   10  100
```

I would like to match rows based on "fruit" and extract the line from df1 if the range between "low" and "high" in df2 is contained within the range "low" and "high" in df1. So expected output would be:

```
    City    fruit   low high  Country   fruit   low high
0   sample1 orange  50  200   Spain     orange  100 20000
1   sample3 orange  50  300   Spain     orange  100 20000
2   sample3 grape   350 1000  Aus       grape   300 10000
```

I figure it could start something like:

```
for sample, subdf in df2.groupby("fruit"):        
        for index, row in subdf.iterrows():
```

Comment: Aren't the first two rows in your expected ouput outside of the range?  In the first row, for example, the low of 50 in `df2` is _not_ contained between between the `low` and `high` of `df1` (100 and 20000, respectively).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with outer join and filtering by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df1 = df2.merge(df1, on='fruit', how='outer', suffixes=('','1'))
df2 = df1[(df1.low1 <= df1.high) & (df1.high1 >= df1.low)]
print (df2)
      City   fruit  low  high Country  low1  high1
0  sample1  orange   50   200   Spain   100  20000
2  sample3  orange   50   300   Spain   100  20000
4  sample3   grape  350  1000     Aus   300  10000
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a left join rather than an outer join.

```
>>> (
    df2
    .merge(df1, how='left', on='fruit', suffixes=('', '_country'))
    .loc[lambda frame: frame.eval('(low > low_country) and (high < high_country)')]
    .reset_index()
    )
   index     City  fruit  low  high Country  low_country  high_country
0      4  sample3  grape  350  1000     Aus          300         10000
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution Alexander, I was incorrect saying "contained within" as I am satisfied if there is partial overlap. However, I think that your solution can also come in handy at some point